# Bmi TypeError when calculating

Tags: python

Ive always used my code like this but when I expand the program it starts saying unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
the code I am using is for a bmi calculator and it dosen't work when I input an expansion to it.

bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)

Comment: Yes. `/` is not supported between strings and floating-point numbers. What is your question about that?

Comment: Please post your entire code. Maybe, you are taking input as strings?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`weight_kg` is a string. Try converting it to a float:

```
bmi = float(weight_kg) / (height_m ** 2)
```